# Perl: Why does for and foreach give me different results?

Tags: arrays, perl

I looked online and everyone seems to say they are used interchangeably.  However, it gave me different results when I was iterating through my array.

I had an array of approx. 60 string elements and were filtering out whatever matched in another array.  But when I used `foreach`, it only saw an array of 45 elements so when I printed the final result, it did not filter everything out.

It was only when I used `for` that it worked as I wanted.  What is the reason behind this?

I managed to solve the problem, now I just want to understand the way this works.  Thanks!

EDIT: So i didn't provide any examples so here's what I did:

```
my $i = 0;
foreach my $item (@array){
    print "\n$i : $item";
    foreach my $exclude_item (@exclude){
        chomp $exclude_item;
        if ($exclude_item eq $item){
            print "\nDEBUG: Removing $item";
            splice @array, $i, 1;
        }
    }
    $i++;
}
```

The above wasn't giving me a complete list of `@array` so when I printed the final result, there were elements inside that should've been filtered out.

So I tried this instead (which worked as I wanted):

```
for (my $i=0; $i < scalar @array; $i++){
    print "\n$i : $array[$i]";
    foreach my $exclude_item (@exclude){
        chomp $exclude_item;
        if ($exclude_item eq $array[$i]){
            print "\nDEBUG: Removing $array[$i]";
            splice @array, $i, 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Just additional info, the `@array` was created by searching for list of subdirectories in multiple folders.  It's possible that `@array` contained duplicates.

Comment: Something else was different. `for` and `foreach` are completely indistinguishable from the lexer onwards. They're two names for exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
# Foreach loop                               \           
foreach my $item (@array)                     > same     \
for my $item (@array)                        /            \
                                                           > different
# Augmented while loop                       \            /
for (my $i=0; $i < scalar @array; $i++)       > same     /
foreach (my $i=0; $i < scalar @array; $i++)  /
```

---

You must not modify an array over which you iterating. From perlsyn,

> If any part of LIST is an array, `foreach` will get very confused if you add or remove elements within the loop body, for example with `splice`. So don't do that.

Therefore,

```
foreach (@array){
   ...
   splice @array, $i, 1;   # XXX Error
   ...
}
```

Note that you may safely modify the elements of an array over which are you iterating.

```
foreach (@array){
   $_ = uc($_);  # ok
}
```

---

Finally, a far better solution:

```
chomp(@exclude);

my %exclude = map { $_ => 1 } @exclude;

@array = grep { !$exclude{$_} } @array;
```

Aside from being much simpler, it scales much much better<sup>[1]</sup>.

---

1. It executes in O(E+A) time, whereas the OP's executed in O(E * A<sup>2</sup>) time.

Comment: I seriously hate/love how stupid you guys make me feel..  Saying that, thanks for the clarification!  I don't understand your solution at all atm, so I'm going to have to spend my friday night on this.

Comment: `my %exclude = map { $_ => 1 } @exclude;` creates a lookup table, so you can efficiently lookup if a string should be excluded. `@array = grep { !$exclude{$_} } @array;` keeps all the elements of `@array` except those present in the lookup table.

Comment: Just for completeness, the hash slice method `my %exclude; @exclude{@exclude} = (1) x @exclude` is twice again as fast. If you only do it once it may not be worth the two lines though.

Answer (score 6):

When people say they are used interchangably, they mean that the `foreach` keyword is just a synonym for the `for` keyword. That means the following two lines mean exactly the same thing:

```
foreach my $item (@array) {...}
for my $item (@array) {...}
```

For the avoidance of doubt I will ignore the `foreach` keyword and use only `for` below.

The following two lines, as you have seen, do not behave identically:

```
for my $item (@array) {...}
for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar @array; $i++) {...}
```

The [manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) advises against adding or removing elements in `@array` in the loop body of the first line, and doesn't say what would be the result.

If the loop body of the second line removes an element in `@array` at or before `$i`, the result will be that the element at new position `$i` will be skipped over. If it adds an element at or before `$i`, the result will be that the element at old position `$i` will be seen by the loop a second time.